# Save SASS to same as origin files

Tags: sass, prepros

I am using sass with prepros compiler and sublime editor. I need to have each scss file complied with the same file name.

For example: 
I currently have-

- header.scss
- content-top.scss
- footer.scss

and they are all compiles into style.css to create one full style sheet.

I wish to have a style folder with

- header.css
- content-top.css
- footer.css

which will be done automatically when saving and compiling like I normally do. 
How can I accomplish this? 
Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check this [link](http://alphapixels.com/prepros/docs/sass-compass.html) out.

It states that you can adjust your project structure (in your case CSS folders) in project settings.

If I remember correctly you may have to buy it so that you can compile more than 4 or 5 Sass files, but I may be wrong.

Also check that you aren't "only" importing sass partials because of this:

> Any Sass and Scss file (i.e. including partials) imported by another 
>   file are not shown in the files list but they are still watched by Prepros. 
>   The parent file is re-compiled whenever any of the imported files are changed.